Maui Toast message doesnt show correct color
I am using the package Controls.UserDialogs.Maui and when i show a toast message i want the toast to be a specific color. On Android this works fine but on iOS this doesnt work. I found one issue that shows the same problem (https://github.com/Alex-Dobrynin/Controls.UserDialogs.Maui/issues/29)
Does anyone know how to workaround this or if theres another package which i can use to show toast messages in a specific color?

CommunityToolkit.Maui have a Toast class but it doesn't allow us to customize the background color. Anyway, I have written a sample method to invoke a custom toast for iOS. Give this a try. Hope this helps.
 public static void ShowToast(string message, UIColor backgroundColor, UIColor textColor, nfloat padding)
    {
        var toast = new UILabel
        {
            Text = message,
            TextColor = textColor,
            BackgroundColor = backgroundColor,
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
            Lines = 0,
            Layer = { CornerRadius = 8, MasksToBounds = true },
            Alpha = 0,
            Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(16),
            LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap
        };

        toast.SizeToFit();
        toast.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(
            0,
            0,
            toast.IntrinsicContentSize.Width + (2 * padding),
            toast.IntrinsicContentSize.Height + (2 * padding)
        );

        
        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var mainView = window?.RootViewController?.View;
        if (mainView == null) return;

        toast.Center = new CoreGraphics.CGPoint(mainView.Frame.Width / 2, mainView.Frame.Height - 100);
        mainView.AddSubview(toast);

        
        UIView.Animate(0.5, () => toast.Alpha = 1, () =>
        {
            UIView.Animate(2.5, 0.5, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut,
                () => toast.Alpha = 0,
                () => toast.RemoveFromSuperview());
        });
    }


This does seem to work, Thanks! I do have to add that the position is out of view on my phone so I had to correct it by setting the center to
toast.Center = new CoreGraphics.CGPoint(mainView.Frame.Width / 2, mainView.Frame.Height / 2);
Thanks a lot!

Also its kinda stupid we need to make this basic component ourselves and neither the package nor maui doesn't have this build in.

Great ! I agree, as basic component as Toast should be provided by Maui with allowing minimal customization like setting colors.
